# Upgraded From Angular 9 to 14 - All api calls in deployed app appear to only call the root/hosted url in request url

Tags: angular

As the title states, I recently updated the application from angular 9 to angular 14. After many trial and errors, I managed to deploy the application via azure devops but noticed that all the network calls by the application is only making the network calls with the request url as the host url.

For example, app is hosted on `https://hostingurl.com`. On the login page, after the user clicks the login button, the app should make a network request to `https://api-endpoint.com/login` to initiate the login process but instead makes a network request to `https://hostingurl.com`, which of course, does nothing.

Has anyone come across this issue before? There has been no changes to the azure portion of the deployment process. Only changes were angular 9 to angular 14 and the app was working properly, deployed, on angular 9. I'm assuming its a config issue on the angular side.

Here is the angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "appName-frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "coverage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build:test"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-coverage": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build:coverage",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "./cypress/coverage.webpack.js"
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "build-dev": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "coverage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build",
            "serverTarget": "appName-frontend:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "appName-frontend:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appName-frontend:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "appName-frontend:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {},
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-run": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-open": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "appName-frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve-coverage",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve-coverage:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "e2e-ci": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "browser": "chrome",
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve-coverage",
            "headless": true,
            "watch": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend:serve-coverage:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-run": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend-e2e:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend-e2e:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-open": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend-e2e:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appName-frontend-e2e:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue on my end. For those in a similar situation, here what's I did

The base url for all the api calls are stored on our env file and during the deployment process, the production tokens are replaced in azure (currently the prod env file base urls are tokens that get replaced during the deployment/release process in azure, such as `#{base_url}`.

The task that handles the replacement of tokens looks for the files `dist/browser/main-es2015.*.js` and `dist/browser/main-es15.*.js` and does a find and replace. Since updating to 14, those files are no longer created and instead `dist/browser/main.*.js` is created and used for the app.

These tokens were never replaced, so the base url got replaced by the host url, as it should, by angular's http. Once I updated the deployment config on azure to look for the correct main file, and not the differential loading files, the deployed app's api calls were functioning as it should.